# Problemas con la Camara en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hice una funcion para tomar una foto con la camara del pc pero no me muestra nada alguien sabe que pasa

```js
const captureVideoButton =
  document.querySelector('#screenshot .capture-button');
const screenshotButton = document.querySelector('#screenshot-button');
const img = document.querySelector('#screenshot img');
const video = document.querySelector('#screenshot video');

const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

captureVideoButton.onclick = function() {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).
    then(handleSuccess).catch(handleError);
};

screenshotButton.onclick = video.onclick = function() {
  canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
  canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
  canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0);
  // Other browsers will fall back to image/png
  img.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/webp');
};

function handleSuccess(stream) {
  screenshotButton.disabled = false;
  video.srcObject = stream;
}
```

```html
<video autoplay></video>
<img src="">
<canvas style="display:none;"></canvas>
```

Comment: te sugiero revisar: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: Hola, disculpa que no pueda responder tu pregunta directamente para ayudarte con tu error, pero puedes revisar este [Link](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) en donde ponen un código de ejemplo para hacer lo que necesitas tu

Comment: Gracias Diego Avila  y Sebastián Miranda voy a revisar los links

Comment: Compas no me funciono no se porque acabo de colocar el codigo y no me tira nisiquiera los botones

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la solucion que encontre se las deseo compartir

```js
var constraints;
var imageCapture;
var mediaStream;

var grabFrameButton = document.querySelector('button#grabFrame');
var takePhotoButton = document.querySelector('button#takePhoto');

var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var img = document.querySelector('img');
var video = document.querySelector('video');
var videoSelect = document.querySelector('select#videoSource');
var zoomInput = document.querySelector('input#zoom');

grabFrameButton.onclick = grabFrame;
takePhotoButton.onclick = takePhoto;
videoSelect.onchange = getStream;
zoomInput.oninput = setZoom;

// Get a list of available media input (and output) devices
// then get a MediaStream for the currently selected input device
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
  .then(gotDevices)
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('enumerateDevices() error: ', error);
  })
  .then(getStream);

// From the list of media devices available, set up the camera source <select>,
// then get a video stream from the default camera source.
function gotDevices(deviceInfos) {
  for (var i = 0; i !== deviceInfos.length; ++i) {
    var deviceInfo = deviceInfos[i];
    console.log('Found media input or output device: ', deviceInfo);
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = deviceInfo.deviceId;
    if (deviceInfo.kind === 'videoinput') {
      option.text = deviceInfo.label || 'Camera ' + (videoSelect.length + 1);
      videoSelect.appendChild(option);
    }
  }
}

// Get a video stream from the currently selected camera source.
function getStream() {
  if (mediaStream) {
    mediaStream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
      track.stop();
    });
  }
  var videoSource = videoSelect.value;
  constraints = {
    video: {
      deviceId: videoSource ? {
        exact: videoSource
      } : undefined
    }
  };
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then(gotStream)
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('getUserMedia error: ', error);
    });
}

// Display the stream from the currently selected camera source, and then
// create an ImageCapture object, using the video from the stream.
function gotStream(stream) {
  console.log('getUserMedia() got stream: ', stream);
  mediaStream = stream;
  video.srcObject = stream;
  video.classList.remove('hidden');
  imageCapture = new ImageCapture(stream.getVideoTracks()[0]);
  getCapabilities();
}

// Get the PhotoCapabilities for the currently selected camera source.
function getCapabilities() {
  imageCapture.getPhotoCapabilities().then(function(capabilities) {
    console.log('Camera capabilities:', capabilities);
    if (capabilities.zoom.max > 0) {
      zoomInput.min = capabilities.zoom.min;
      zoomInput.max = capabilities.zoom.max;
      zoomInput.value = capabilities.zoom.current;
      zoomInput.classList.remove('hidden');
    }
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('getCapabilities() error: ', error);
  });
}

// Get an ImageBitmap from the currently selected camera source and
// display this with a canvas element.
function grabFrame() {
  imageCapture.grabFrame().then(function(imageBitmap) {
    console.log('Grabbed frame:', imageBitmap);
    canvas.width = imageBitmap.width;
    canvas.height = imageBitmap.height;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(imageBitmap, 0, 0);
    canvas.classList.remove('hidden');
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('grabFrame() error: ', error);
  });
}

function setZoom() {
  imageCapture.setOptions({
    zoom: zoomInput.value
  });
}

// Get a Blob from the currently selected camera source and
// display this with an img element.
function takePhoto() {
  imageCapture.takePhoto().then(function(blob) {
    console.log('Took photo:', blob);
    img.classList.remove('hidden');
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('takePhoto() error: ', error);
  });
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

button {
  margin: 0 10px 20px 0;
  width: 99px;
}

button:last-of-type {
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

input#zoom {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.borderBelow {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
}

video {
  margin: 0 12px 20px 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  button {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    width: calc(33% - 5px);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 720px) {
  video {
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <button id="grabFrame">Grab Frame</button>
    <button id="takePhoto">Take Photo</button>
    <div class="select">
      <label for="videoSource">Video source: </label>
      <select id="videoSource"></select>
    </div>
    <input class="hidden" id="zoom" type="range" step="20">
  </div>

  <video autoplay class="hidden"></video>
  <img>
  <canvas class="hidden"></canvas>

</div>
```